# Type erasure and variadic templated member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, type-erasure

The example below is a minimal, maybe not so good example of a well known idiom.
It compiles and it is so ugly in order to be able to maintain it minimal, because the question is not about the idiom itself.

```
struct Foo {
    virtual void fn() = 0;
};

template<class T>
struct Bar: public Foo {
    void fn() override {
        T{}.fn();
    }
};

struct S {
    void fn() { }
};

int main() {
    Foo *foo = new Bar<S>{};
    foo->fn();
}
```

What I'm struggling with since an hour ago is how to change it (or even, if there exists an alternative idiom) to introduce a variadic template member method.
Obviously, I cannot modify the `fn` function of the `Foo` class, because it's a virtual one and virtual specifier doesn't goes along with templates. The same is valid for the `fn` specification of `Bar`, because it has to override somehow the one in the base class.

**Note.**

For I strongly suspect that this question could be one of the greatest *XYProblem* ever seen, I'd like also to give a brief description of the actual problem.

I have a class that exposes two templated member methods:

- the first one accepts a template class `T` that is not used immediately, instead it should be *stored* somehow in order to be used later.
- the second one accepts a variadic number of arguments (it is actually a variadic templated member function) and those arguments should be perfectly forwarded to a newly created instance of `T`.

Well, the problem is far more complex, but this is a good approximation of it and should give you an idea of what's the goal.

**Edit**

I guess that it is somehow similar to higher order functions.
I mean, what would solve the problem is indeed a templated function to which to bind the first argument, but as far as I know this is impossible as well as any other approach I've explored so far.
Any viable solution that expresses the same concept?

Comment: Your larger goal is to combine runtime and compile-time dynamism in a way that I suspect isn't possible, but I'll be curious to see what cleverer people than me come up with.

Comment: @zwol I have exactly the same feel, that's why I've asked on SO!! :-)

Comment: Definitely, *member function templates cannot be virtual*

Comment: @A.S.H I know that, I don't want to use template and virtual specifiers at the same time, instead I hope the target is clear (my English is far from being good, so let me know if the question is not clear enough).

Comment: I salute the effort you made to explain your goal, but still, I admit I fail to see what exactly you are seeking. it is not a problem of English at all :). At best, I would go templating the base class itself, so it can have virtual methods. But I am not sure this achieves your final goal.

Comment: @A.S.H. No, sorry, the base class cannot be templated. Imagine I have a pointer to that type: if you go templating it, all the benefits of that idiom are gone. :-)

Comment: You are running into a fundamental limitation of virtual functions and template parameters not mixing together. Type erasure cannot work in this situation. The closest you can come to type erasure is for the first function to return a templated helper class: "auto factory=object.getFactory<T>();" and the class being subsequently instantiated via "factory.construct(parameters...)", instead of calling a second "object" method.

Comment: ... continued. This would not be perfect type erasure. You cannot type-erase the `factory` helper class away, in this case.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I invite you to post an answer with a minimal example of what you described, for it sounds really interesting even though it looks to me that it won't solve the problem (I'd vote up it anyway for being interesting). The question is about how to do that using type erasure or alternative techniques. ;-)

Comment: Can you add example code how this would work for, say, *two* template arguments, so that it's clear what's being generalized here?

Comment: I added time ago the *note* part, that is about what it is meant for. Would you like me to translate it in pseudo code (cannot write real code, because I have not the solution yet)?

Comment: @skypjack: Not even pseudo-code, but real code for a hypothetical `template <typename T1, typename T2> struct Bar2` would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I mentioned in the comments is the following approach:

```
template<typename T> class Factory {

public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    auto construct(Args && ...args)
    {
        return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

So now, your first exposed class method will be something like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto getFactory() {

    return Factory<T>();
}
```

So:

```
auto factory=object.getFactory<someClass>();

// Then later:

factory.construct(std::string("Foo"), bar()); // And so on...
```

Instead of `construct()` you could use `operator()` too, so the second part of this becomes, simply:

```
factory(std::string("Foo"), bar()); // And so on...
```

As I mentioned, this is not really type erasure. You can't use type erasure here.

Having given this a few minutes' more thought, the reason that type erasure cannot be used here is because a given instance of type erasure must be "self contained", or atomic, and what you need to do is to break atomic type erasure into two parts, or two class methods, in your case.

That won't work. Type erasure, by definition, takes a type and "erases" it. Once your first function type-erases its class method template parameter, what you end up with is an opaque, type-erased object of some kind. What was type-erased is no longer available, to the outside world. But you still haven't type-erased your constructor parameters, which occurs somewhere else.

You can type-erase the template class, and the constructor parameters together. You can't type-erase the template class, and the constructor parameters, separately and then somehow type-erase the result *again*.

The simple factory-based approach, like the one I've outlined, would be the closest you can get to results that are similar to type erasure, if both halfs of your desired type-erasure appear in the same scope, so you can actually avoid type-erasure, and instead rely on compiler-generated bloat.

Comment: Upvoted because of the effort, anyway I'm not sure it solves the problem. Besides that, maybe you gave me a good idea. Tomorrow I'll have a go and be back with more questions.

Comment: As you already mentioned, it doesn't solve the problem for a simple reason: either I need the type `T` when I get the `Args...` to create the factory, or somehow I must create a factory that cannot be type-erased and type-erase it to store it somewhere.

Comment: That is simply impossible in C++, since templates cannot be virtual. The only way to do something like this is for the classes's constructors to accept a type-erased parameter pack. Then, you type-erase the class, and provide a type-erased virtual function that accepts a type-erased parameter pack, and then invokes the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I also agree that you cannot do exactly what you want here.  I will post what I think the closest option is (at least a close option that is different from SamVarshavchik's answer).
I don't expect this answer to solve your problem exactly, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.

```
    struct Delay // I have no idea what to call this
    {
        template <class T>
        void SetT()
        {
            function_ = [](boost::any params){return T(params);}
        }

        template <class ... Args>
        boost::any GetT(Args ... args)
        {
            return function_(std::make_tuple(args...));
        }

      private:
        std::function<boost::any(boost::any)> function_;
    };
```

The obvious limitation of this is that anyone calling `GetT` will somehow have to know what `T` was already, though you can query the `boost::any` object for the `type_info` of its class if that helps.  The other limitation here is that you have to pass in `T`'s that take a `boost::any` object and know what to do with it.  If you cannot have `T` do that, then you can change `SetT` (or create a new member function) like this:

```
    template <class F>
    SetTFactory(F f)
    {
        function_ = f;
    }
```

and then use it like:

```
    Delay d;
    d.SetTFactory([](boost::any s){return std::string(boost::any_cast<const char*>(s));});
    auto s = d.GetT("Message");
    assert(s.type() == typeid(std::string));
```

This of course introduces a whole new set of difficulties to deal with, so I don't know how viable this solution will be for you.  I think regardless of anything else, you're going to have to rethink your design quite a bit.